# cygwin can't find my files

Tags: linux, windows-8, cygwin

I just downloaded CYGWIN for Windows 8. I'm using it because my professor wants us to do everything through the command line and I'm used to the linux setup on the computers in our labs, as opposed to trying to figure out cmd commands that go with the linux. When I open CYGWIN and type "ls" nothing shows up. When I type "cd ../.." it takes me to what seems to be the file structure for CYGWIN and it won't let me go up anymore after that. I feel like this probably is just a setup error. Will someone please help me out.

Comment: What does `pwd` show? BTW you can go to `c:\foo` by typing `cd /cygdrive/c/foo`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From cygwin, you can get to the C: disk as

```
cd /cygdrive/c/
```

Check here: [for permanent solution](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#windows).

As mentioned there: create a directory for each
    of your disks and mount them:

```
> cd /
> mkdir c
> mount c: /c
> mkdir d
> mount d: /d
> ...etc
```

Now you can directly go to the c: drive, for example:

```
> cd /c
```

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add some quick syntax for all UNIX programmer.

```
$ cd c:    "It will give U shortcut access to /cygdrive/c"
$ cd d:    "It will give U shortcut access to /cygdrive/c"
```